# Problems with IsPostBack

Tags: c#, .net

I have an .aspx page which sends a letter to a customer if a button on that page is clicked. Onclick the page calls itself, so the mail send class is in the same file. However I do not want the mail sent when the page is simply loaded. I want it send the letter when the button is clicked, so, I'm trying with the following code:

```
void page_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SendMail();
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you put the sendMail function  in the button click event?

Comment: Are you sure the `Page_Load` method is actually being called at all?

Comment: Yes, Page_Load is being called for sure since if I remove the IsPostBack condition, it will send the mail normally.

Comment: Nt working can also mean the mail is not being sent by the server. Did you check this? Does it work without the IsPostBack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `Button`'s `Click Event` then?

What you are talking about is you want to send an email only when a specific button is `clicked`. Then why not register to it's click event instead of bloating your `page_load` with extra code?

Button's click event is raised only when that button's click causes a `postback`. So, that's your best option.

Comment: The case is that my button also calls a JavaScript function. If I create a <asp:Button onclick="Button_click"> how am I going to call the JavaScript function as well with that same click?

Comment: Ok, the issue is resolved. Created an <asp:Button> and found the way to run JavaScript by OnClientClick="javascript:myfunction()". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Make an event handler for the button's click event (Just double click the button in Visual Studio's Designer).

Using `Page_Load` will result in emails being sent out when the user posts back in any circumstance, not just your button click.

Comment: The case is that my button also calls a JavaScript function. If I create a <asp:Button onclick="Button_click"> how am I going to call the JavaScript function as well with that same click?

Comment: Ok, the issue is resolved. Created an <asp:Button> and found the way to run JavaScript by OnClientClick="javascript:myfunction()". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the page does not find the correct event handler for the Page_Load, check the case and correct it to Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

See if this works (replace your `page_Load` method with the following code):

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SendMail();
    }
}
```

You are currently relying on [`AutoEventWireup`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814745) functionality to hook up your page events.  This is slow and problematic and may be the cause of your issue.  The method I gave you overrides `Page.OnLoad` and should correct the problem as well.

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Gave an error message that there's nothing to override.

Answer (score 0):

The **Page_Load** event is raised every time the page is posted, well by means of **postback** or **callback**, if you want to use server side events you should call you  *SendMail* method in the button's *click event*:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
   {
      /*occurs the first time the page is loaded*/
   }        
  if (IsPostBack)
  {
     /*occurs every time a postback is raised (e.g. by form submission) */
  }
  if (IsCallback)
  {
     /*occurs every time a callback is raised, e.g. by generating callbacks by means of AJAX/
  }
}
protected void  SendMail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { SendMail(); }
```

Read more at MSDN: [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).